# Pathfinding algorithm with direction and weights

Tags: python, path, path-finding

Say you have two arrays, representing the wave *speeds* and *directions* of an area at sea. The speeds are integers and the directions are degrees. These arrays correspond to an area of latitude-longitude (not that it matters).

Then, say you'd like to find the shortest (fastest) path from A to B (given that the sailing directly into waves slows you down, and it slows you even more if the wave speeds are big). You'd both have to take into account the wave speed, and the wave direction.

From what I've seen, Dijkstra and A* are not able to solve these kinds of problems. Is there anyone that has dealt with something similar before?

Comment: What have you seen with A* and Dijktra? How should one take into account wave speed and direction? How does sailing into waves directly slowes one down? Please specify the problem more so that it becomes a programming problem.

Comment: I've seen solutions to directed graphs that do not allow traversing at angles to edges. Wave speed is simply the weight of the directed edge. The problem is, how does one take into account that a boat could sail at an angle to the waves, not only in the same direction.

Comment: I think I might understand what you mean, but still it could help to clarify the problem further. So far I'm not sure if it is a physics problem or a programming problem. What is your model for speed of boat depending on wave speed and direction of propagation?

Comment: its possibly by using Nodes and edges with different length in different directions

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a pathfinding library for python. I've edited the A* to be able to handle this kind of situation. However its in very early development so it might not work.
and it doesn't have a doc. to use it just create a cluster witch is the basic class that handles all the pathfinders.

```
SIZE = 10
arr = np.ones((1, SIZE, SIZE),
               dtype=np.int)

clus = pypathing.nodeGraph.Cluster()
clus.build(arr, pypathing.directions.fullDiagonal)
```

where `pathfinding.directions.fullDiagonal` states that all diagonal movement is allowed (witch I would advise in this situation but you can alsow use `pypathing.directions.noDiagonal` witch wont use any diagonal movement).

than you can get the Edge connecting 2 clusters by:

```
e = clus.getEdge(clus.getnode((0,0,0)), clus.getnode((0,0,1)))
```

than you can use this to set how fast the current is in the direction from `clus.getnode((0,0,0))` to `clus.getnode((0,0,1))`

```
e.nodeMoves = 1
```

and than just get the path by:

```
clus.runAstar(start, end, speed=1)
```

where `start` is the starting node, `end` is the end node of the path and speed is the speed of the ship.

Comment: make sure you have the right direction for the nodes